# How do you run an executable file whose name and location could vary with the Windows command prompt?

Tags: cmd

I am trying to create a script that will repair and reinstall a program. The problem is that the only place I can find an installer for the program is in C:/ProgramData. The folder name that it is saved in is randomly generated and the actual name of the file will vary depending on which version of the program they have installed 1.1, 1.5.1, etc. I need to create a command that will search for the executable file and run it. An example of what the installer might look like is program1.5.1.exe.

I have already tried using findstr, dir, etc., but I have not had any luck.

Here are some of the commands that I have tried.

cd C:/ProgramData
findstr /s program*.exe

cd C:/ProgramData
dir /s program*.exe

When I use the findstr command, it keeps running and never finds the executable. When I run the dir command, it tells me that "Volume in drive C has no Label", tells me my serial number, and then it says "File Not Found."

Comment: `findstr` is for locating text content (*find string*), not for searching for filenames. `dir /s program*.exe` works if you know the program name, or at least enough of it to match before the wildcard. If the `dir` command is telling you the file is not found, then it wasn't found, which means either it doesn't exist or you're searching for the wrong name..

Comment: Alrighty, so this is what I am trying now. `cd C:/ProgramData`. Then I run `dir /s program*` and this lists the directory that it is in. How can I pass this directory to the cd command? I tried `dir /s program* | cd`, but that did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to run an executable that is in a folder with an unknown name and that has a file name that will be different depending on the version of the program. I was trying to find and run a test file that I called "program1.3.0.exe". Note, I ran this in a batch file so if you are running this directly in the command prompt you will need to type `%i` instead of `%%i`.

`for /r C:/ProgramData %%i in (program*.exe) do start %%i`

- The `for` command searches through the directory
- `/r` tells it to search within the subdirectories
- `C:/ProgramData` is the directory that it will search within
- `%%i` is a variable that holds each file that it finds
- `in (program*.exe)` tells it to only use results that start with program and end with .exe
- `do start %%i` will run each executable that it finds